# What does the preserve keyword do in xkb config files

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to know what the preserve keyword does in the xkb_types section of a custom xkb keymap.

Here is an example from an existing config file:

```
type "FOUR_LEVEL_SEMIALPHABETIC" {
    modifiers= Shift+Lock+LevelThree;
    map[Shift]= Level2;
    map[Lock]= Level2;
    map[LevelThree]= Level3;
    map[Shift+LevelThree]= Level4;
    map[Lock+LevelThree]= Level3;
    preserve[Lock+LevelThree]= Lock;
    map[Shift+Lock+LevelThree]= Level4;
    preserve[Shift+Lock+LevelThree]= Lock;
    level_name[Level1]= "Base";
    level_name[Level2]= "Shift";
    level_name[Level3]= "Alt Base";
    level_name[Level4]= "Shift Alt";
};
```

I am interested in these two lines:

```
    preserve[Lock+LevelThree]= Lock;
    preserve[Shift+Lock+LevelThree]= Lock;
```

Unfortunately neither the Archwiki, which has a very good xkb config guide, nor the official website of xkb (which does not have much information in general) seem to have any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

XFree86 documents it in [How to further enhance XKB configuration; Defining new layouts](http://www.xfree86.org/current/XKB-Enhancing4.html#8). Copying the relevant fragment for the benefit of the reader,

> Usually, all modifiers introduced in `modifiers=<list of modifiers>` list are used for shift level calculation and then discarded. Sometimes this is not desirable. If you want to use a modifier for shift level calculation but you don't want to discard it, you may list in `preserve[<combination of modifiers>]=<list of modifiers>`. That means, for a given combination all listed modifiers will be preserved. If the Lock modifier is preserved then the resulting symbol is passed to internal capitalization routine regardless whether it has been used for a shift level calculation or not.

Comment: Actually that was X11R6.  My page on [key-modifiers](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/modified-keys.html) has a link to the [Xkb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/XKB/xkblib.html) documentation, which hasn't gotten much change since **1996**.

Comment: I'd amend it - X11R6 came out after XFree86 started, it was incorporated into XFree86 ~1996, and (looking at the source-tree...) the doc in X11R6 was in FrameMaker (not text).  I suppose someone could make a fairly long answer giving the history of this stuff...  But as far as I know, X11R7 just changed the version number -- no real content changes.